# Hosting WPF application within IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wpf, iis

I have created a WPF application (contains 8 projects).
one project is of type (Class Library) ,this dll contains class which implement
System.Web.IHttpHandler as the following.

```
public class ReportFileHttpHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        // some code
    }
 }
```

this HttpHandler is designed to interrupt the IIS request and handle the requrest of the xml file.

I also created a web.config file which exists inside this dll.

```
 <system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <add verb="*" path="*.xml" type="ReportFileHttpHandler"  name="ReportFileHttpHandler"/>
</handlers>
```

Every thing is good here.
I want to do the following : I want to test the code inside the "ReportFileHttpHandler" ,so I need to host the my WPF application within (inside) the IIS to make test.
in this way I can write URL inside the Browser (which end with .xml) to execute the code in the method

```
public void ProcessRequrest(HttpContext context)
```

How can I Host the WPF application inside the IIS ?

any idea will be helpful, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a webapplication in IIS say MyWPFApp.
2. Set physical path of application to directory where ReportFileHttpHandler assembly resides say C:\xxx\ReportFileHttpHandler\bin\Debug.
3. Make sure that ReportFileHttpHandler.dll and web.config are in same directory.
4. Browse url http://localhost/mywpfapp/myfile.xml in browser.
5. If you attach w3wp.exe process corresponding to app pool of your web application in Visual Studio, you should be able to debug your handler dll.

Comment: thank you a lot it seems very helpful, even if I did not try it yet. 
I just have a question about the w3wp.exe (what is it? how can I attach it ?)
I am completely new to the ASP.NET web developing. @Pankaj Kapare

Comment: Hi, I am sorry but your solution did not work.
I am receiving error